# Access the spring security in different ports getting principle data as a String 'anonymousUser'

Tags: java, spring-security

I have an application running in my local 8100 and my server side code is executed in 8065 it has implemented `Spring Security` as Java config. When I hit the login server code from 8100 ionic browser window . I got the principle object data only have string as `anonymousUser`.
  I printed in my server side code for `Authentication`  and `Principle` data. Below pasted the code .

For `Authentication`

`Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

`auth` data is ,

`org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS`

For `getPrincipal`

`Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

`principal` data

`anonymousUser` this string only it has. Below i pasted my Security config java class code .

**Security Config** Java Class

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user/createsocialuser");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();

        loginFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login/loginFailure");

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .regexMatchers("/login.*").permitAll()
        .regexMatchers("/admin.*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .regexMatchers("/user.*").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("j_username") 
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login/loginSuccess")
            .permitAll()
            .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied/403").and().csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

**Login Html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="loginform" data-ng-submit="doLogin(loginform,userDetails)">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.login.email" id="j_username" placeholder="Enter username" name="j_username" >
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.login.password" id="j_password" placeholder="Enter password" type="password" name="j_password">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" id="loginerror" role="alert">
            invalid usermame or password
          </div><br/>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Si in</button>
      </form>
```

**Login Js**

```
$scope.doLogin = function(loginform,userDetails) {
            if (loginform.$valid) {
             console.log('$parent.login.email',angular.toJson(self.login.email));
             console.log('$parent.login.password',angular.toJson(self.login.password));
             var loc = 'http://localhost:8080/Test_10030';
              $http.post(loc+'/j_spring_security_check?j_username='+self.login.email+'&j_password='+self.login.password)
             .success(function(data){ 
                   console.log('Server data =>',angular.toJson(data));
                 if(data.responseError == "loginFailed"){
                     alert("user name pasword incorrect")
                       console.error('Server data =>');
                     $log.log("Error login Credentials: ",JSON.stringify(data));
                     $location.url('login');
                 }


           if(data.responseSuccess == "success"){
              if(data.result != null){
                  var serverData = data.result;
                  console.warn('Server data =>',angular.toJson(serverData));
                  $rootScope.userData= serverData;
                  $location.url('/home');
              }
           }
           }).error(function(data){          
            //callback 
            console.log('Error Some Internal server Error',data);
           });
             } else {
              $log.log("form is invalid!");
              if (self.isNewUser) {
               loginform["username"].$dirty = true;
               loginform["usrtel"].$dirty = true;
              } 
              loginform["email"].$dirty = true;
              loginform["password"].$dirty = true;
             }
            };
```

**Login COntroller** Java

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class LoginController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/loginSuccess",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public  ResponseWrapper  create(Principal principle) {  
            System.out.println("-------***************----------------"); 
            try {
                System.out.println("principle data=>"+principle)// NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
                System.out.println("-------sucess********----------------");
                ResponseWrapper wrap = new ResponseWrapper();

                Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
                System.err.println("Principal dara=>"+principal);
                wrap.setResult(principle);
                wrap.setResponseSuccess("success");
                return wrap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**UserDetail Class**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SecurityUserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserDao gpuser_Dao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("............" + username);
        GpUser user = gpuser_Dao.findUser(username);
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        String rol = null;
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No User found");
        } else {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            // Access DB and get the roles and assign
            Object obj = user.getAuthorities();
            System.out.println("obje data=>" + obj.toString());
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")); 
            userDetails = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);
            /** ADDING ROLES-Creating authentication object with roles **/
            Authentication authentication = new UserAuthenticationToken(user, userDetails,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            // Set the authentication
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

**BootSecurityUserDao .java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class BootSecurityUserDao implements IUserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GUser findUser(String username){
        try{

            String login = "select * from guser where username=:username";
            Query result = entityManager.createNativeQuery(login,GUser.class)
                    .setParameter("username", username);
            List<GUser> list  = result.getResultList();
            System.out.println("size of user list : " + list.size());
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                GUser user_from_db = list.get(0);
                return user_from_db;
            }

        }catch(DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any other code add for particular role like `anonymousUser` or `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` in my security java config class. I added `permitAll()` for `\login` related `URLS` . Or the spring security itself have any code for overcome this problem like I have a confusion .

Comment: @PrasannaKumar ur right but in my ionic app called two request when I logged in time , for spring security login url

Comment: one is `GET` and `POST` @PrasannaKumar

Comment: @PrasannaKumar actually it supposed to be one request that is for `POST` but here the ionic app automatically added `GET` request , now only I saw the chrome `network` console ..,

Comment: @PrasannaKumar `GET` as a first request it has 302 status , then redirects to POST request `POSt` req has status 302 then it redirects to loginSuccess method in Java controller inside

Comment: Oh ho..! than that is problem with app it seems..Because your spring security is working fine...

Comment: @PrasannaKumar that i have principle object it has only value as a String `anonymusUser`

Comment: yup because `GET` request may be overriding your assigned roles

Comment: show the code where you are assigning roles..other code seems ok

Comment: @PrasannaKumar sir, In the db every  user has `role`  like `ADMIN` and `USER` ,

Comment: @PrasannaKumar  sir , I hard coded the role for every user in the coulmn f user table  ..exactly I am not having any roles assigned code . Normally  the user signned Up in site

Comment: @PrasannaKumar I added the login controller inside that I `sysout` the `auth` and `principal`  objRef has data .above pasted the objRef data in starting point of code .., is that kay?

Comment: @PrasannaKumar I have tried your code integrated with mine , that time I got an error (Null pointer exc) . I found it where it is also in our controller you passed the `principal` to `AssignRoles.java`

Comment: `principal` it has only `anonymusUser` String , thats `NPE` , so I pasted ,my db spring security checking code , could yu pls tell me is there any thing wrongly i did in my validation or any thing i need to add more plz @PrasannaKumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122836/discussion-between-sakthisureshanand-and-prasanna-kumar).

Comment: check the updated answer..in ur code roles were assigned but authentication object and principal object was not set..now principal object is set  to GUser and roles from db are assigned to authentication object

Comment: @PrasannaKumar sir, in my login controller `Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` this line still getting as a string `anonymousUser` only ,

Comment: @PrasannaKumar sir , I printed those lines after set Authentication happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be Your DB roles are not assigning properly.Do one thing,validate the user and then assign the roles by yourself like below.

**AssignRoles.java**

```
public class AssignRoles implements UserDetailsService { 

    Public Principal principalObject;
    //getter setter

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException { 
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            //Access DB and get the roles and assign
            grantedAuthorities.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Role_User"));

            boolean enabled = true;  
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;  
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;  
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;   
            UserDetails userDetails =  new User(userName,password,enabled,accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,grantedAuthorities); 

           /**ADDING ROLES-Creating authentication object with roles**/
            Authentication authentication = new UserAuthenticationToken(principalObject, userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            //Set the authentication 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);  //Authentication is assigned,Now check security context user will have roles
            return userDetails;
    }

}
```

**UserAuthenticationToken.java**

```
public class UserAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final Object principal;
        private Object credentials;

        /**Store the principal object(you can store any object like userbean anything) as principal,userdetails as credentials and authorities in Authentication object**/
        public UserAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            super(authorities);
            this.principal = principal;
            this.credentials = credentials;
            super.setAuthenticated(true);
        }

        public Object getCredentials() {
            return this.credentials;
        }

        public Object getPrincipal() {
            return this.principal;
        }

    }
```

**LoginController.java**

```
public  ResponseWrapper create(Principal principle) {    
    try {
        ResponseWrapper wrap = new ResponseWrapper(); 

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

         /**ADD THIS**/
        AssignRoles assignROles = new AssignRoles();
        assignRoles.setPrincipalObject(principal);
        assignRoles.loadUserByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName())  //send username

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() //It will print assigned roles

        return wrap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Modify your `UserDetail.class` to

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BootUserService implements  IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private BootSecurityUserDao gpuser_Dao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("............"+username);

        GUser gUser = gpuser_Dao.findUser(username);
  UserDetails userDetails = null;
        if (gUser== null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No User found");
        } else {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            //Access DB and get the roles and assign
            grantedAuthorities.add( new       SimpleGrantedAuthority(gUser.getAuthority())); //If not fetched fetch from db and assign
            //you can add any number of roles like
            /** grantedAuthorities.add( new       SimpleGrantedAuthority("RoleJustAsString")); **/

            userDetails =  new  User(userName,password,enabled,accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,grantedAuthorities); 

           /**ADDING ROLES-Creating authentication object with roles**/
            Authentication authentication = new UserAuthenticationToken(gUser, userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            //Set the authentication 
                   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 
        }
        System.out.println("-=--------------user----"+user.toString());
        return userDetails;

    }
}
```

Remove `AssignRoles.java` and keep `UserAuthenticationToken` class.

Comment: I added these lines in my userdetail.java class and follwing i got as a output  ,` Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: output for `principal` objRef is `GpUser [id=2, firstName=cenation, lastName=cena, middleName=john, username=admin, password=12345, languagepreference=null, primaryemail=null, phonenumber=null, screenname=null, startdate=null, licenseid=null, lastaccess=null, mustresetpassword=null, accestype=null, roles=[GpAuthority [logger=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog@5542984d, id=2, authority=ROLE_ADMIN]], newuser=false]`

Comment: and in my GpUser class has a method `getAuthorities` so I printed `System.out.println("princ"+user.getAuthorities());` ouput for this line i got it like `[ROLE_ADMIN]` @Prasanna Kumar

Comment: @Sakthi  its working fine.. print this `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

Comment: sir , where do i add the above line because in login controller I added this line right nw It has `anonymusUser` line is `Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: If I am trying to add your line in my controller that `getAuthorities` instead of `getPrincipal` its `undefined` in Authentication like it tells

Comment: Add in userDetail.class before returning

Comment: Not to login Controller..add in UserDetail class as last line..before return userdetails;...i want to know whether the authentication object set to spring security context is correct or not

Comment: problem is in my `login controller` i don't get that role correctly as well as other information but  in my userdetail.class holds every data correctly ..,

Comment: sir , I found the issue of `ROLE_ANONYMUS` because I am running the ionic  app in 8100 port ,

Comment: In my server port is running in 8080 , if the url is success in my spring security is redirecting  to success url like `\login\loginSuccess` in my desktop application automatically added the `set-cookie`..,

Comment: but my ionic app is not added that set cookie content while redirecting that is the root cause of this issue .., I tested in postman how na? I took the jsessionId for the spring security url and I manually added in to the cookie header in postman and hit login/loginSuccess it retrieve all the roles and user related info perfectly ..,

Comment: if u have any suggestion how to set the session id in redirecting url like success our failure url inside java  , could you please give any suggestion sir

Comment: You can add it as flash attribute or try by setting to request scope or to header..But i am not sure about that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122889/discussion-between-prasanna-kumar-and-sakthisureshanand).